# «Глубокий вырез декольте» — тавтология?

Tags: тавтология

Википедия:

> Декольте́ (фр. Décolleté, «с отсечённой шеей, без шеи») — глубокий
>   вырез в женской одежде, частично открывающий плечи и/или грудь с
>   эстетическими и эротическими целями.

Ожёгов:

> Декольте — 1. нескл., ср. Большой вырез в верхней части женского
>   платья. Глубокое д. 2. неизм. О женском платье: с таким вырезом.
>   Платье д.

Даль:

> Декольте — франц. нареч. сущ. несклон. женский открытый наряд, когда шея, часть
>   груди и руки выше локтя обнажены; голошейка.

Всё-таки, корректным ли является выражение «глубокий вырез [в] декольте» или в слово «декольте» уже включен «глубокий вырез» и такое выражение — ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Декольте – это вырез горловины верхней части одежды.

ДЕКОЛЬТЕ 1. Вырез в женском платье, открывающий шею, плечи, верхнюю часть груди, спину. Глубокое д.

Поэтому **декольте может быть разной формы и глубины**, это не обязательно только глубокий вырез (глубокое декольте), но повтора слов "декольте" и "вырез" не должно быть, это тавтология.

Виды декольте:

[Выбираем платья с декольте: советы и рекомендации стилистов | cutur.ru](http://cutur.ru/publ/garderob/platja/vybiraem_platja_s_dekolte_sovety_i_rekomendacii_stilistov/9-1-0-559)

Comment: Декольте - _разновидность_ выреза (по определению), однако в буквальном переводе термина слово "вырез" отсутствует, т. е. нет повторения слова в другой форме. Почему же видовое наименование "вырез" (который бывает и напр. на спине) в сочетании уточняющим обозначением типа выреза нужно считать тавтологией?

Answer (score 4):

**«Если у вас кривые ноги — носите глубокое декольте»**
Кристиан Диор

***Декольте*** (франц. collet - "воротник" и лат. collum - "шея") – это **вырез** на одежде, который обнажает шею, плечи, часть груди или спины.

Основная задача ***любого декольте*** – подчеркнуть женственность, изящность, красоту женского тела и придать нотку пикантности его обладательнице.
При этом не стоить забывать о том, куда и с какой целью вы направляетесь, надев ***глубоко декольтированный наряд,*** чтобы не попасть в неловкую ситуацию. ***Слишком большие вырезы*** неуместны в деловых кругах, на встречах с серьезными людьми, если вы работаете в учреждениях детского образования.
[**История и виды декольте**](http://elfina.com.ua/blog/vidy-dekolte)

По определению,  **декольте** и есть, собственно, **вырез**.
Поэтому мы говорим: *глубокое, V-образное, асимметричное, круглое декольте*.
Или: *глубокий, V-образный, асимметричный, круглый вырез*.

Таким образом, **выражение «глубокий вырез декольте» является тавтологией.**

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы: «глубокий вырез декольте» — тавтология. Правильно: «глубокое декольте».